# Getting Invalid syntax in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to learn python programming. 
I tried the following code but it shows the below error.

like you have Consider an array `Z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]`

like output generate an array `R = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], ..., [11,12,13,14]]`

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.arange(1,15)

print(Z)

size = 4
step = 1

R = [Z[i : i + size] for i in range(0, len(Z), step)]

print(R)

rank = assert np.array_equal(R[1,:],np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]))

print(rank)
```

But when check `np.array_equal` it's give me error.

> rank = assert np.array_equal(R[1,:],np.array([2, 3, 4, 5]))
>                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You cannot assign an assert statement to a variable

Comment: you can show me demo please?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement   Asserts throw an error if your check does not work. You can not assign them. You can not show a demo of what does not work. Use `i=22` then `assert i ==42`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the creation syntax so you only get "slices" of size 4:

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.arange(1,15)

print(Z)

size = 4
step = 1

# Fixed: len(Z)-size not len(Z)
R = np.array( [Z[i : i + size] for i in range(0, len(Z)-size , step)] ) 

try:
    assert R.shape == (len(Z)-size,size) 

except ( AssertionError,IndexError ):
    print(f'Error asserting:     R.shape == ({len(Z)-size},{size})')

else: # print success message if assert is ok:
    print(f'Asserted:            R.shape == ({len(Z)-size},{size})')
```

This assertion will throw:

```
try:
    assert R.shape[1] == 99
except AssertionError :
    print("Error asserting:      assert R.shape[1] == 99")
```